# Turn off formatting for T4 template generated code in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, t4

I've been running into an issue with Visual Studio 2017 where a T4 template that is generating a bunch of C# classes from metadata is auto formatting the files based on the settings in Visual Studio's C# formatting options. I have changed these options and verified that the changes are reflected in the generated code. Basically what is happening is the T4 code generation completes and then Visual Studio begins to open every single file that was just generated and format it.

I've turned off formatting for the C# language in Tools and Options and disabled .editorconfig files just in case it was picking up one of those, but the template generation seems to ignore this. The problem is that these T4 templates generate ~2000 files which are then formatted which causes TFS to check out the file and eventually crashes visual studio about halfway through the formatting. Is there an option somewhere I'm missing to turn off formatting for generated code? This was not an issue prior to our recent upgrade to VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

The default setting for Visual Studio 2017 is that it doesn't do anything to template files on the onset, so in order for this to happen it should be something you've added to your VS environment. Few things to check...

1. Any Visual Studio extensions or features. T4 is not well supported so a lot of the extensions and features out there have bugs in them. It maybe that the software provider hasn't thought of your problem yet and you should raise a bug with them. If your using an extension or feature to assist in your software development of T4 then try a different one. Additionally extensions or features not related to T4 also format files. An examples are Productivity Power Tools or Resharper
2. Under the properties of your template files check the Custom Tool value. It may not seem like the obvious choice, but occasionally if this is not set to `TextTemplatingFileGenerator` or `TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor`, you need know why it's not set that way. There might be a perfectly good reason for why its set differently, just so long as you know what that reason is
3. Normally templates use the *.tt extension, however there are many different acceptable extensions that suit different occasions. Make sure the extension isn't named the same as an existing extension, that formats files in its own way
4. If the features for C# are off, you might want to consider turning off all formatting features one by one incase the templates files are being considered as part of a different language or under a different option. Start with Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > Advanced > Pretty listing as an example. That may give you a clue as to where the setting is being affected.

HTH